# Bootstrap not showing data from REST endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

Hitting one of my REST endpoints using bootstrap table, but the data us now showing at all. Here's what I'm working with (see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgwod3fb/):

```
$('#data-table').bootstrapTable({
    url: '/rest/endpoint,
    striped: true,
    iconSize: 'btn-sm',
    cache: false,
    search: true,
    searchOnEnterKey: true,
    searchText: 'Search for a member...',
    columns: [
        {
            checkbox: true,
            field: 'check',
            clickToSelect: true,
            searchable: false
        },
        {
            field: 'email',
            title: 'Name',
            sortable: true,
            clickToSelect: false
        },
        {
            field: 'role',
            title: 'Type',
            sortable: true,
            clickToSelect: false
        },
        {
            field: 'actions',
            title: 'Actions',
            sortable: false,
            clickToSelect: false,
            formatter: function () {
                return '<img class="control" src="/assets/images/delete.svg" alt="Delete">';
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Based on what I can see I'm getting the correct data from the endpoint, but the table isn't showing the proper data. See below for the response:

[image]

Where it fails is with the `getData()`method:

[image]

If I reset the value of data in the console the data will show properly:

```
 data = this.options.data;
```

Any ideas? Does Bootstrap Table expect the response to be *exactly* the same structure as the columns?

#### Update 1

I tried using this approach, but still no avail... Such a widely used widget this is definitely a show stopping issue.

I got the data using an ajax call like the table does and I cleaned the data so we have:

```
 {
      checkbox: true,
      email: 'user@foo.com',
      role: 'foo',
      actions: undefined
 }
```

Here is the code I used below:

```
if (_$dataTable) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(), json = null;

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:3000/members/list/01tuee743h9muf6', function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });


    $.when(deferred).done(function (json) {
        json = Utils.dataCleanup(json);

        _$dataTable.bootstrapTable({
            striped: true,
            iconSize: 'btn-sm',
            cache: false,
            search: true,
            searchOnEnterKey: true,
            searchText: 'Search for a member...',
            data: json,
            columns: [
                {
                    checkbox: true,
                    field: 'check',
                    clickToSelect: true,
                    searchable: false
                },
                {
                    field: 'email',
                    title: 'Name',
                    sortable: true,
                    clickToSelect: false
                },
                {
                    field: 'role',
                    title: 'Type',
                    sortable: true,
                    clickToSelect: false
                },
                {
                    field: 'actions',
                    title: 'Actions',
                    sortable: false,
                    clickToSelect: false,
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<img class="control" src="/assets/images/delete.svg" alt="Delete">';
                    },
                    events: function () {
                        // TODO: add some events...
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It was linked to:

```
 searchText: 'Search for a member...',
```

This will autofill the search bar with content and will attempt to find the user based on that search term. Removing this property solved the issue.